# Integration by Parts [Answer Provided].

Tags: integration

The function:

$$f(x) = x^2/e^x$$

Perhaps, someone could show how the solution becomes:

$$\int f(x)dx=-e^{-x}(x(x+2)+2)$$

It is likely that my integration by parts contains an error.

Comment: It should be $e^{-x}$, not $e^x$, in the final answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $u=x^2 \Rightarrow du=2xdx$ and $dv=e^{-x}dx \Rightarrow v=-e^{-x}$ thus $$\int\frac{x^2}{e^x} dx = -x^2e^{-x} + \int 2xe^{-x} dx$$ Now we perform it again on the resulting integral: $r=2x \Rightarrow dr=2dx$ and $ds=e^{-x}dx \Rightarrow s=-e^{-x}$ thus $$\int 2xe^{-x}dx=-2xe^{-x} +2\int e^{-x} dx=-2xe^{-x}-2e^{-x}$$ therefore $$\int\frac{x^2}{e^x} dx =  -x^2e^{-x}-2xe^{-x}-2e^{-x}=e^{-x}(-x^2-2x-2)$$

Comment: plus the constant of integration, "+c"

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\begin{array}{l}\int {\frac{{{x^2}}}{{{e^x}}}dx}  = \int {{x^2}{e^{ - x}}dx}  = \int {{x^2}d( - {e^{ - x}})}  = \\ - {x^2}{e^{ - x}} + 2\int {x{e^{ - x}}dx}  =  - {x^2}{e^{ - x}} + 2\int {xd( - {e^{ - x}})}  = \\ - {x^2}{e^{ - x}} - 2x{e^{ - x}} + 2\int {{e^{ - x}}dx}  = \\ - {x^2}{e^{ - x}} - 2x{e^{ - x}} - 2{e^{ - x}} =  - {e^{ - x}}({x^2} + 2x + 2)\end{array}$$

Comment: plus the constant of integration, "+c"

Answer (score 0):

*Let $$I=\int x^2e^{-x}dx\\ =x^2\int e^{-x}dx-\int\left(\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)\left[ \int e^{-x}dx\right]dx\right)dx\\=-x^2e^{-x}+\int2xe^{-x}dx\\=-x^2e^{-x}+2\left[x \int e^{-x} dx-\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}(x) \int e^{-x}dx \right)dx\right]\\=-x^2e^{-x}-2xe^{-x}-2e^{-x}+c\\=-e^{-x}(x^2+2x+2)+c \quad \blacksquare$$*

Answer (score 0):

Using tabular integration, you can write

$\hspace{.6 in} \textbf{u} \hspace{.9 in} \textbf{dv}$

$\hspace{.6 in} x^2 \hspace{.73 in} e^{-x}dx$

$\hspace{.6 in} 2x \hspace{.6 in}-e^{-x}$

$\hspace{.6 in} 2 \hspace{.79 in} e^{-x}$

$\hspace{.6 in} 0 \hspace{.64 in} -e^{-x}$

Taking the products on the diagonals going down from left to right and then adding them with alternating signs gives

$\hspace{.4 in}-x^2e^{-x}-2xe^{-x}-2e^{-x}+C=-e^{-x}(x^2+2x+2)+C$